# Expand macro into xparse \SplitList macro

Tags: expansion, xparse

I had help making a macro to process a list of arguments separated by `;` into an `itemize` environment. To achieve this, `xparse` was used.

When I tried to wrap the lists of arguments in a macro, nothing happened though. How may I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\newcommand\insertitem[1]{\item #1}

% xparse-command I had help with
\NewDocumentCommand\myList{>{\SplitList{;}}m}
  {\vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    \begin{itemize}
      \ProcessList{#1}{ \insertitem }
    \end{itemize}
  }

\newcommand\someStuff{One; two; three}

\begin{document}

\myList{One; two; three}

Now trying to expand macro content

\myList{\someStuff}

\end{document}
```

In `\myList{One; two; three}` the result is as desired, an `itemize`d list. The latter example, `\myList{\someStuff}` is not working. I believe the solution to my problem probably lies somewhere in the question [Passing multiple arguments from ProcessList (xparse) to a macro. Result to be used in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54972/passing-multiple-arguments-from-processlist-xparse-to-a-macro-result-to-be-us), but I'm not currently able to understand where...

EDIT: the intended use for the storing of arguments in a macro is basically to make my life a bit easier. I have made a template structure to a progression plan in the subjects I teach, where I need to print for instance the desired main competences my students should have achieved during the planned period. As those competences (and more) are wrapped into a messy `longtable` environment, and I am planning to make the template into a class when I have time to learn how to do just that, it would be very convenient for me to have a block in the beginning of the document looking a bit like this:

```
\maincompetences{Competence one; competence two, etc.}
\learninggoals{Main goal one; main goal two; etc.}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TeX doesn't expand arguments when it's absorbing them. So in the second case the argument that's passed to `\SplitArgument` is `\someStuff` that doesn't contain semicolons.

One might force the expansion of the first token in the argument, but this might create other problems.

A lower level solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\myList}{sm}
 {
  \begin{itemize}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \holene_mylist:o { #2 } % expand the argument (once)
   }
   {
    \holene_mylist:n { #2 }
   }
   \end{itemize}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_holene_mylist_input_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \holene_mylist:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_holene_mylist_input_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_holene_mylist_input_seq
   {
    \item ##1
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \holene_mylist:n { o }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\someStuff{One; two; three}

\begin{document}

\myList{One; two; three}

Now trying to expand macro content

\myList*{\someStuff}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*You* are deciding when expanding the argument or not, with the *-variant.